# Rules of algebra with Normal distribution

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution

As part of my self study for Financial Economics, I came across simplifying the following expression,

$$\sigma Z_{0.25} + (2\sigma)(Z_{0.5} - Z_{0.25})$$

where $Z$ are independent [Brownian motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process) ($Z_0 = 0$ and $Z_t-Z_s \mathtt{\sim} N(0, t-s)$.

It is simplified as,

$$\sigma N(0, .25) + 2\sigma N(0, .25) = N(0, .25\sigma^2) + N(0, .25 \times 4\sigma^2)$$
$$= N(0, 1.25\sigma^2) = \sqrt{2.5}\sigma Z_{0.5}$$

However, if I *simplify* the first expression to $\sigma (2Z_{0.5} - Z_{0.25})$, I get a different Normal distribution, $N(0, 1.75\sigma^2)$ which is $\sqrt{3.5}\sigma Z_{0.5}$.

**Edit**: Here's how I did the above simplification,

$$\sigma Z_{0.25} + (2\sigma)(Z_{0.5} - Z_{0.25})$$
$$= \sigma Z_{0.25} + 2\sigma Z_{0.5} - 2\sigma Z_{0.25}$$
$$= 2\sigma Z_{0.5} - \sigma Z_{0.25}$$
$$= \sigma (2 Z_{0.5} - Z_{0.25})$$

using basic algebra.

So, obviously, the Brownian motion variables and Normal distributions don't support all of algebra. So, what subset of the algebraic rules are allowed when dealing with these? Is there somewhere these are set out that I can refer to? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "independent" Brownian motion?  The terms $Z_t$ and $Z_s$ normally refer to values at "times" $t$ and $s$ within the *same* Brownian motion.  Although (by definition) this has independent Normal *increments,* it is not the case that $Z_t$ and $Z_s$ are independent random variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$2\sigma (Z_{0.5}-Z_{0.25})\neq \sigma (2Z_{0.5}-Z_{0.25})$

$2\sigma (Z_{0.5}-Z_{0.25})= \sigma (2Z_{0.5}-2Z_{0.25})$

You just forgot to distribute the 2 to both terms in the parentheses. The textbook is definitely correct and you definitely don't need any special math to simplify that expression.

---

edit: I see your problem. You're actually right in the sense that you can't just subtract off coefficients on random variables. Recall what "subtracting off" actually means in terms of 6th grade algebra. $2x-x=x$ if and only if $2x = x + x$. In this case, $2\sigma Z_{0.25} \neq \sigma Z_{0.25} + \sigma Z_{0.25}$.

To convince yourself, try simplifying the distributions (i.e. plugging in the variances) in $\sigma Z_{0.25} + 2\sigma Z_{0.5} - 2\sigma Z_{0.25}$. You get $Z_{.25*\sigma^2} + Z_{2\sigma^2} - Z_{\sigma^2}=Z_{.25*\sigma^2} + Z_{2\sigma^2} - Z_{\sigma^2}$.

The "rules of algebra" still apply where they're relevant, but in this case it takes some care not to apply them where they aren't. Then again I probably would done the same thing in your position.

Comment: There is another $\sigma Z_{0.25}$ that you forgot which when added, will simplify to the expression I presented in my question.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Post the full steps you're using to simplify, because I just double checked my answer and it's right.

Comment: The simplification I'm taking about is of the first expression in my question, in full. That is $\Z_{0.25} + 2\sigma(Z_{0.5}-Z_{0.25})$, which when simplified gives the expression I wrote in my question. In your answer, you didn't copy the $\sigma Z_{0.25}$ part. You copied only part of my initial expression and simplified it.

Comment: I meant $\sigma Z_{0.25} + 2\sigma (Z_{0.5} - Z_{0.25})$. Sorry, was on my iPad.

Comment: What else is there to simplify? You're simplifying the first expression incorrectly and therefore the rest of your steps give you the wrong answer.

Comment: I'm not sure why I'm not able to make my point clear here, but I added notes on how I simplified to the question. Please let me know if it still isn't clear. Thank you for all your effort.

Comment: I understand now. I edited my answer.

Comment: Ah, okay, I think I get it now. Need to be extra careful with these *variables* :). Thank you for your explanation.